# Parachain does not producing blocks

Tags: parachain, substrate-parachain-template, relay-chain, parachain-collator, parachain-launch

When I link a relay chain to the parachain using the Local chain type, it successfully generates blocks. However, upon changing the chain type to live in chain_spec.rs, block production fails, and an error is reported stating that `collation wasn't advertised to any validator`.